# How to get channel in TestSupportBinder without using Transformer

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I am trying to use TestSupportBinder to write tests for spring cloud stream application. All examples I found, including [official documents](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/Brooklyn.RELEASE/reference/html/_testing.html) and [official github](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/tree/master/spring-cloud-stream-test-support/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/stream/test/example), are to test a `Processor` with a `Transformer`. These tests use `Tranformer` to get output Channel, and feed the Channel object into `messageCollector.forChannel` method to poll output.

However, instead of using the provided `Processer`, I wrote my own Interface. I can't find a way to get the required Channel object in test code. I had tried to autowire my Interface into test class to get Channel object but ended with  `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Channel [MY_CHANNEL] was not bound by class org.springframework.cloud.stream.test.binder.TestSupportBinder`.

Answer (score 1):

The error message means that the channel `MY_CHANNEL` is not registered into MessageCollector. and, this indicates, your channel `MY_CHANNEL` from the interface wasn't declared with `EnableBinding` in your application. Do you have `@EnableBinding(MyOwnInterface.class)` in your application (with MyOwnInterface declaring the `MY_CHANNEL` channel)?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My application code is available in [another post]( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43446135/spring-cloud-stream-kafka-dispatcher-has-no-subscribers-error). My test code is to vertify submitted request will get a message in "approved" channel. So,   MY_CHANNEL is actually the "approved" channel.

Comment: I find that `messageCollector. forChannel` method accepts `MessageChannel` but not `SubscribableChannel`. Passing a `SubscribableChannel` to  `messageCollector. forChannel` leads to the exception.

Comment: Along with the above, you can't register channels marked `@Input` with TestSupportBinder. Only channels marked `@Output` will work, and they must be of type MessageChannel in the binding interface.

Answer (score 1):

After taking a look at the spring docs [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/_testing.html) I've noticed it seems that intentionally they only track the output channel, and not the input one.

For example, see:

> **For outbound message channels**, the TestSupportBinder registers a
>   single subscriber and retains the messages emitted by the application
>   in a MessageCollector. They can be retrieved during tests and have
>   assertions made against them.

Also, in the example they just demonstrate on the output channel:

```
messageCollector.forChannel(processor.output()).poll()
```

Seems to me that they expect you to track your input channel by the calls to the listening method.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work for input channel. Only for output.

Not work: collector.forChannel(inputStream.inputStream()).clear();

```
public interface InputStream {
String INPUT_NAME = "offices";

@Input(INPUT_NAME)
SubscribableChannel inputStream();
}
```

Work: collector.forChannel(outputStream.outputStream()).clear();

```
public interface OutputStream {
String OUTPU_NAME = "offices";

@Output(OUTPUT_NAME)
SubscribableChannel outputStream();
}
```